# Drupal 7 Views, Nested User > Content views filter by exposed date

Tags: 7, views

I have a nested View. The outer view is a list of users, and that view has a field which includes a content View of everything that user has created. I have chosen to expose the date of that inner view in the hopes I can have an exposed filter on the outer view to control them. Ideally, I'd choose a month and year in the main view and see how much content, if any, each user has created in the last month.

Since the outer view is not a content view, I can't choose a date filter and hook that into the inner view fields. And I need to show all users regardless of whether or not they have content, so I can't go to a Content > Content nested view. Is there a date filter that's independent of content type that I could choose to inherit the exposed filter from the inner view, or that I could use to send a contextual filter to the inner view?

Answer (score 0):

In the outer view, add a relation
Via this relation add the field filters (for example - field_date)
In the outer view field which references the inner view you can pass arguments -> field_date.

In the inner view -> add contextual filters, which will be field_date.

I hope this gives you some direction.